# Enable CheckBox with DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, displayfor

I have a web application made with ASP.NET MVC 5. In this application I have a view which display a list of information.

In this list I display a `boolean` information with `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.valide)`. So a `CheckBox` is displayed and it's checked and disabled.

How can I do to remove the `disabled="disabled"` from the `CheckBoxes` ?

Comment: DisplayFor is providing readonly representation and EditorFor should be used if you want to be able to change the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.valide)
```

or

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.valide)
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have an enable `checkbox` with `DisplayFor` then you need to have a [template](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/).

Create a `DisplayTemplates` folder under `Shared` folder an add a partial view to it and name it something for example (`_myTemplate`) and then paste the following code to it:

```
@model bool
@Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c)
```

Then you can have an enable `CheckBox` when using `DisplayFor` helper (just don't forget to specify the template that you've created):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(c => c.Valide, "_myTemplate")
```